# Application Insights not reporting custom properties and call stack

Tags: c#, uwp, azure-application-insights

I'm logging different exceptions with the following method that accepts the exception as well as some context information string.

```
public void LogException(string notes, Exception e)
{
    var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "notes", notes }
    };

    telemetry.TrackException(e, properties);
}
```

The exceptions are reported correctly, but they are missing

- The custom property "notes"
- The call stack

[image]

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, are you sure your LogException method is getting called? Application insights logs exceptions automatically so you could be seeing the default logging. As for call stacks, because UWP apps compile to .net native you can't get a meaningful call stack (if somebody out there knows different, please share because it's very frustrating)

Answer (score 1):

is the exception actually *thrown* ?  are you catching that exception?  if you just do

```
client.TrackException( new Exception() );
```

there won't be a stack frames on some OS's / runtimes.

but if you do

```
try
{
   throw new Exception();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    client.TrackException( e );
}
```

you *will* get a stack trace.  something about the act of throwing the exception actually populates the underlying frame the sdk uses.

for your custom property, that should be showing up right away, although sometime's there's a lag between a new custom property being sent the first time, and when it shows up in metadata as a field to display.  Also, you're limited to 200 distinct named custom properties, so if you've already sent 200 other properties, the "notes" field will just get thrown away.

in general for UWP / release / .net native, you *should* still have frames, they just won't be very readable, they'll be memory addresses, but there's still a stack of them, and if you have the pdb's, etc, you can reverse engineer what was where.

though the above looks like "catastrophic failure" exceptions that might not have stack frames available?